# Append new key to an existing array in an object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an existing JSON array:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [set] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => agenda
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => first aid
                )
        )

)
```

I need to add a new key to it, so the final JSON result is something like this:

```
set: [{
    name: 'agenda',
    value: 'Agenda'
}, {
    code: 'first aid',
    value: 'First Aid'
}],
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data->set as  $k => $row) {
    $result['name'][$k] = $row->name;
    $result['value'][$k] = ucwords($row->name);
}
```

But I have ended up with:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => agenda
            [1] => aid kit

        )
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => Agenda
            [0] => First Aid
        )
)
```

How can I merge the above so the name and value keys are in pair rather then being separate?

Comment: what exactly do you want the final array to look like?

Comment: See the final result above.

Comment: `$result = array_map(function($setPart){return array('name'=>$setPart->name, 'value'=>ucwords($setPart->name));}, $object->set);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `$row` directly to modify your existing `$data`:

```
foreach ($data->set as $row) {
    $row->value = ucwords($row->name);
}
```

To do it the way you are attempting:

```
$result = $data;
foreach ($data->set as $k => $row) {
    $result->set[$k]->value = ucwords($row->name);
}
```

Notice, `$row` is an object.

Comment: Since `$row` is an object, you don't actually need to use a reference. (It still works either way; just isn't necessary.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Good to know.  I only ever do this with arrays.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Your example works as well. Bit shorter, but same desired result. Since I prefer less code, I will accept  your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your try this

```
$result = array();
$count = 0;
foreach ($data->set as  $k => $row) {
    $result[$count]['name'] = $row->name;
    $result[$count]['value'] = ucwords($row->name);
    $count++;
}
```

result this

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => agenda
                    [value] => Agenda
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => first aid
                    [value] => First Aid
                )
        )
```

Comment: Did you even test this?

Comment: Yes, I did try that, but the wanted result is not the same.

Comment: my mistake, i edit and test result this => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => agenda [value] => Agenda ) [1] => Array ( [name] => first aid [value] => First Aid ) )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your existing object, you can just set the value property directly.

```
foreach ($data->set as $row) {
    $row->value = ucwords($row->name);
}
```

If you want to create a result without modifying your original object or leaving references to its internal objects, you can clone each of the internal objects and add the new properties to the cloned objects.

```
$result = array();
foreach ($data->set as  $k => $row) {
    $obj = clone $row;
    $obj->value = ucwords($row->name);
    $result[$k] = $obj;
}
```